# facing issue to get xpath of the element present in Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, python, java, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am using robot framework for automation and want to click on element **print button**(Please refer attach image for Html Code) on Shadow Dom.

I have created variable using js path but it is not working. Can any one help to find exact xpath of the element

[image]

** Variables **

`${chrome}`    `chrome`

`${print}`     `${printIRCF1}`

```js
${JSPath} = document.querySelector('print-preview-app').shadowRoot           
                ...  .querySelector('print-preview-sidebar')  
                ...  .querySelector('print-preview-button-strip').shadowRoot  
                ...  .querySelector('controls')  
                ...  .querySelector('action-button').shadowRoot
```

Can any one help me with the correct JsPath or with xpath so that I can use it in my code

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be good if you attached what you tried and what were the results. Right now it looks like you have not had a go yourself.

Answer (score 1):

the below methods are working for me.

**SeleniumLibrary**

1. In Chrome, right click on the element that you want to interact and select the "copy > JS Path" (in this example, I want to click the search button)
   [image]

2. This is my JS Path for the search button/icon: `document.querySelector("body > pw-shell").shadowRoot.querySelector("app-header > div > paper-icon-button:nth-child(5)")`
3. Then I used the `Execute JavaScript` keyword. Something like this:

`${element}=     Execute JavaScript    return document.querySelector("body > pw-shell").shadowRoot.querySelector("app-header > div > paper-icon-button:nth-child(5)")`

`Click Element    ${element}`

4. This selected the search button/icon for me.

**Browser**

1. I used the same JS Path and combined them with the `Click` keyword

   `Click    body > pw-shell >> app-header > div > paper-icon-button:nth-child(5)`

Personally I prefer Browser library in such cases. It is possible to interact with the Shadow DOM element easily.

(a) https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-browser/Browser.html#Cascaded%20selector%20syntax

(b) https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-browser/Browser.html#Click

Comment: on this page I am clicking on print ICON
https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/elections/assembly-elections/karnataka/news/karnataka-assembly-elections-pms-appeal-congs-survival-jdss-relevance-at-stake/articleshow/99104392.cms

Comment: Print Button Actual Js path by doing right click-->copy--->copy js path:

document.querySelector("body > print-preview-app").shadowRoot.querySelector("#sidebar").shadowRoot.querySelector("print-preview-button-strip").shadowRoot.querySelector("div > cr-button.action-button")

Comment: Tried below path with Browser Library can you please confirm it is correct or not as it is not working for me:
Click    body > print-preview-app >> print-preview-sidebar.side >> print-preview-button-strip >> div > cr-button.action-button

Comment: Error
waiting for locator('body > print-preview-app').locator('print-preview-sidebar.sidebar').locator('print-preview-button-strip').locator('div > cr-button.action-button')
TimeoutError: locator.click: Timeout 20000ms exceeded.

Comment: Hi @kahirrao, this is working for me: `click    id=toi-article-container-99104392 >> css=div.eg6hg >> css=a`. Let me know if it works for you also, thanks.